# Reler tags scripts e style com js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Possuo essas tags scripts que servem para ajustar e dar funções a um carrossel. Porem estou adicionando o carrossel assim que clico em um botão, porem como a pagina ja foi renderizada esses scripts acabam nao tendo efeito no carrossel que foi adicionado. Como posso fazercom que essas tags scripts sejam "relidas" assim que clico no botao? Acredito que se forem lidas pelo navegador apos eu ter adicionado o carrossel, os scripts sutam efeito.

Answer (score 0):

Recarregar os scripts não irá ajudar.

Dependendo do seu framework, é possível que ele tente iniciar alguns plugins automaticamente quando a window é carregada, mesmo que você remova e insira os scripts novamente, os eventos do window.onload não serão invocados novamente.

Nesse caso se você decidir adicionar outro carrossel após a página já estar carregada, você têm que iniciar esses plugins manualmente. Como fazer isso? Eu não tenho como te responder, vai variar da API do seu framework. Provavelmente algo como `$('#meu_carrossel').carrossel()`, tente verificar a documentação.